# How can I declare and initialize a Discriminated Union value defined in F# within C#?

Tags: c#, f#

How can I declare and initialize a Discriminated Union value defined in F# within C#?

**F# Code:**

```
namespace Core

[<AutoOpen>]
module EventStore =

    type Events =
        | BuyRequested  of RequestInfo
        | SellRequested of RequestInfo
```

RequestInfo is defined as the following:

```
namespace Core

[<AutoOpen>]
module Entities =
    type RequestInfo = { 
        AccountId : string
        Symbol    : string
        Quantity  : int 
    }
```

**C# Client:**

```
var myEvent = new Events.NewBuyRequested(requestInfo); // Doesn't compile
```

I attempted to reference this [link](http://bugsquash.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/algebraic-data-type-interop-f-c.html) so that I can reference the example below:

```
type Shape =
| Circle of float
| Rectangle of float * float
```

C#:

```
var circle = Shape.NewCircle(23.77);
var rectangle = Shape.NewRectangle(1.5, 2.2);
```

But I do not see any methods exposed for my DU case values (i.e. BuyRequested, SellRequested).

Comment: Deleted new from "new Events.NewBuyRequested". It works now.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already discovered, the `New...` methods are not constructors, but static methods. For the sake of completeness, I wanted to add the following:

- For all union cases that have arguments, the F# compiler generates a static method of name `"New"` plus the name of the union case.
- For all union cases that do not have arguments, a static read-only property is generated, that has the same name as the union case.

For example, in this union,

```
type U = 
    | U1
    | U2 of int
```

you get:

```
> let members = typeof<U>.GetMembers();;
val members : System.Reflection.MemberInfo [] =
  [|U get_U1(); Boolean get_IsU1(); U NewU2(Int32); Boolean get_IsU2();
    Int32 get_Tag(); Int32 CompareTo(U); Int32 CompareTo(System.Object);
...
```

The individual cases are:

```
> typeof<U>.GetMember("get_U1");;
val it : System.Reflection.MemberInfo [] =
  [|U get_U1()
      {Attributes = PrivateScope, Public, Static;
       CallingConvention = Standard;
       ContainsGenericParameters = false;
       CustomAttributes = seq [[Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilationMappingAttribute((Microsoft.FSharp.Core.SourceConstructFlags)8, (Int32)0)]];
...
> typeof<U>.GetMember("NewU2");;
val it : System.Reflection.MemberInfo [] =
  [|U NewU2(Int32)
      {Attributes = PrivateScope, Public, Static;
       CallingConvention = Standard;
       ContainsGenericParameters = false;
       CustomAttributes = seq [[Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilationMappingAttribute((Microsoft.FSharp.Core.SourceConstructFlags)8, (Int32)1)]];
```

The `CompilationMappingAttribute` is the one that identifies them as coming from union cases, and contains the order in which they were defined.